# Modified message with signalr

Tags: asp.net-core, web, signalr

I write a realtime online chat(group, more than 2 in room) with asp.net core, signalR and database ms sql. I need implement modification and delete message and then show changes for other user. How can i do it?
I dont look for no information on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function with SignalR from a client to the server to delete or modify the message and reply to the entire group (assuming that each chatroom is a SignalR group).

Another way of doing it is with REST, where you can do PUT/PATCH or DELETE for the message and "stream" changes to the entire group.